# Query 3 tables in 1 query - miss the last one

Tags: sql, pdo

I want to have the following result:

```
| # | Country | Percent | Nb bookings |
| 1 | France  | 20%     | 10 bookings |
| 2 | Canada  | 80%     | 8  bookings |
```

My actual db are like that:

Table 1: **___Kardex**

```
  KDX_Id (exemple 9)
  ...
  KDX_PostalAddress_Country (example: FR)
```

Table 2: **___Bookings**

```
  BOO_Id
  BOO_ClientId (link with table 1, = 9)
```

Table 3: **___CountryList**

```
  CTY_Code (link with table 1, = FR)
  CTY_en (should show France)
```

My SQL query in PDO is the following:

```
SELECT KDX_PostalAddress_Country,
       COUNT(KDX_Id) * 100 /
  (SELECT COUNT(KDX_Id)
   FROM ___Kardex) AS KDX_CountryPercentage,
       COUNT(KDX_Id) AS KDX_CountryCount
FROM ___Kardex
WHERE KDX_HotelId=:hotel_id
GROUP BY KDX_PostalAddress_Country
ORDER BY KDX_CountryPercentage DESC
```

But I can't get the country name (CTY_en), just it code (KDX_PostalAddress_Country).

I have try to insert an INNER JOIN without success.

```
INNER JOIN ___CountryList
ON ___Kardex.KDX_PostalAddress_Country=___CountryList.CTY_Code
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT CTY_en,
       COUNT(KDX_Id) * 100 /
  (SELECT COUNT(KDX_Id)
   FROM ___Kardex) AS KDX_CountryPercentage,
       COUNT(KDX_Id) AS KDX_CountryCount
FROM ___Kardex
INNER JOIN ___CountryList
ON ___Kardex.KDX_PostalAddress_Country=___CountryList.CTY_Code
WHERE KDX_HotelId=:hotel_id
GROUP BY KDX_PostalAddress_Country
ORDER BY KDX_CountryPercentage DESC
```